# Google App Engine + Jersey + JSP results in NOT_FOUND

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, jersey, jax-rs

Currently I'm working on my first Google App Engine application. I use a combination of Jersey (JAX-RS) and JSP 2.0 with custom tags to separate the lay-out from the application logic.

The application that I created runs perfectly fine in the local sandbox (started using Maven appengine:devserver), but when I run the exact same code at Google I get an "Error: NOT_FOUND" error for the same call. The log at GAE says:

```
2013-04-12 12:37:38.520 /rest/home 404 ...
2013-04-12 12:37:34.034
  com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
    xxx.rest
2013-04-12 12:37:34.308
  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses: Root resource classes found:
    class xxx.rest.HomeResource
2013-04-12 12:37:34.308
  com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init: No provider classes found.
2013-04-12 12:37:34.619
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17.1 02/28/2013 12:47 PM'
2013-04-12 12:37:38.422
  xxx.rest.HomeResource <init>: HomeResource constructor
2013-04-12 12:37:38.427
  xxx.rest.HomeResource displayHomepage: Display home
```

The last two lines show that the HomeResource is there and that it is called. It looks like this:

```
@Path("/home")
public class HomeResource {

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HomeResource.class);

    public HomeResource() {
        log.info("HomeResource constructor");
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response displayHomepage() {
        log.info("Display home");
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/home")).build();
        //return new Viewable("/home");
    }

}
```

The JSP files are located in `WEB-INF/views` and the custom tags in `WEB-INF/tags` as specified in the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.JSPTemplatesBasePath</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/views/</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.WebPageContentRegex</param-name>
        <param-value>/(img|js|css|(WEB-INF/tags)|(WEB-INF/views))/.*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The location of the tags is specified in the JSP as:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
```

This should be correct since the JSP gets compiled without a problem.

Can you please point me in any direction that helps me solve this problem? Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**
It appears to have something to do with the location of the JSP template. When I replace the `Viewable` with a static `String` all works as expected. How are the JSPs in `WEB-INF/views` referenced?

Comment: My initial guess is that your application is deployed with different context paths in your dev and appengine environment, and hence, the URL is different

Comment: @NilsH How can this change the URL? The log shows that the resource is there and that the right method within the resource is called. Or does it change one of the other paths?

Comment: I think your right about view resolving since the controller is executed. Can you tune logging levels to give more output? What string are you using when it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally cracked it... It had indeed to do with the path in the `Viewable`. I changed it to:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response displayHello() {
        return Response.ok(new Viewable("/views/hello")).build();
    }

}
```

Furthermore I moved the `views` folder containing the JSPs to the parent of `WEB-INF` and removed some lines from the `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>xxx.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Test</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And now it works like a charm!